# How to combine NLog Targets with Microsoft ILogger filters?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, nlog

We are using NLog in our .net 5.0 Web API and feel like log levels are set in multiple places. Is there a way we can configure nLog to use the app settings and ignore nLog.config log levels?

**nlog.config**:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" levels="Trace,Debug,Info,Warn,Error,Fatal" writeTo="NLogTarget"/>
</rules>
```

**AppSettings.json:**

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of NLog are you using? Notice NLog 4 always adhere to Microsoft LoggerFactory-config in appsettings. And NLog 5 will by default ignore MIcrosoft LoggerFactory-config by default, unless explicit specified `NLogProviderOptions.RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false`.

Comment: NLog version is 4.7.8.

Comment: Are you only using Microsoft ILogger-object or also directly using NLog Logger-object ? (Ex. `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`)

Comment: Do you want to disable log information directly?

Comment: @RolfKristensen We are using the Microsoft ILogger for logging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With NLog v5 then [NLog.Extensions.Logging ignores the filters](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter) configured in Microsoft LoggerFactory from `appsettings.json`.

Most users gets confused by having 2 log-filtering systems, and expects when using NLog that it is NLog filters that applies. Therefore NLog v5 has changed to ignore Microsoft LoggerFactory filters by default.

It is recommended to configure the filtering using the NLog-configuration, as it will give less surprises like this:

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" finalMinLevel="Info" /> <!-- Overrides previous rule -->
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="NLogTarget" />
</rules>
```

You can also use [${configsetting}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer) to resolve the default-loglevel from `appsettings.json` like this:

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" finalMinLevel="Info" /> <!-- Overrides previous rule -->
    <logger name="*" minLevel="${configsetting:Logging.LogLevel.Default:whenEmpty=Debug}" writeTo="NLogTarget" />
</rules>
```

It is still possible to configure NLog to respect the filtering configured in Microsoft LoggerFactory (from `appsettings.json`), by configuring `NLogProviderOptions.RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false` when calling `AddNLog` or `UseNLog`. Then one can just do this:

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="NLogTarget"/>
</rules>
```

Notice you can also have the entire NLog config in `appsettings.json`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

Comment: Thanks, it works.